# Sobel Edge Detection output for 16bit grayscale image

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, graphics, edge-detection

I've seen many Sobel Edge Detecting Operations in C++ and C#, but I'm having great difficulty converting the code to operate on a 16bit graphic.  Most of the code I've seen is programmed to operate on R.G.B style bitmaps.  The graphic I have is in a ushort[] array with intensity values in each row,col pixel.

The following is the code I've come out with:  (The issue is, that its not quite working...) With a fudge factor in place, it is finding edges perhaps, but it is also finding a lot of noise.

However if I save the original file as a JPG, and run it into a another alternative Sobel-Edge-Detector C# code that accepts Bitmaps, it is a lot better... almost no noise!  Shouldn't my 16bit Grayscale version be better?!  But it must be my code is just not up to snuff.  I'm not understanding the logic.

```
    public void sobel()
    {

        ushort[] pixels = new ushort[9];
        ushort[,] imageData = image_array[0].GetArray();
        ushort[,] imageOut = (ushort[,])imageData.Clone();
        uint xDim = (ushort)(imageData.GetLength(1) - imageData.GetLength(1) % regions);
        uint yDim = (ushort)(imageData.GetLength(0) - imageData.GetLength(0) % regions);

        double intensityX = 0.0;
        double intensityY = 0.0;
        double intensityTotal = 0.0;
        int limit = 1000000; //Just arbitrary junk number

        int filterOffset = 1;

        for (int offsetY = filterOffset; offsetY <
            yDim - (filterOffset+1); offsetY++)
        {

            for (int offsetX = filterOffset; offsetX <
                xDim - (filterOffset+1); offsetX++)
            {
                //intensityX = intensityY = 0;
                //intensityTotal = 0;

                pixels[0] = imageData[offsetY - 1, offsetX - 1];
                pixels[1] = imageData[offsetY - 1, offsetX];
                pixels[2] = imageData[offsetY - 1, offsetX + 1];
                pixels[3] = imageData[offsetY, offsetX - 1];
                pixels[4] = imageData[offsetY, offsetX];
                pixels[5] = imageData[offsetY, offsetX + 1];
                pixels[6] = imageData[offsetY + 1, offsetX - 1];
                pixels[7] = imageData[offsetY + 1, offsetX];
                pixels[8] = imageData[offsetY + 1, offsetX + 1];

                intensityX = pixels[8] + 2 * pixels[5] + pixels[2] - pixels[0] - 2 * pixels[3] - pixels[6];
                intensityY = pixels[8] + 2 * pixels[7] + pixels[6] - pixels[2] - 2 * pixels[1] - pixels[0];

                //intensityTotal = Math.Sqrt((intensityX * intensityX) + (intensityY * intensityY));
                //intensityTotal = Math.Abs(intensityX) + Math.Abs(intensityY);
                intensityTotal = intensityX * intensityX + intensityY * intensityY;
                //int sobel = (int)Math.Sqrt((xSobel * xSobel) + (ySobel * ySobel));

                //if (intensityTotal > MaximumValue)
                  //  intensityTotal = MaximumValue; //Presumably Black

                //if (intensityTotal < -1000) //1000 fudgefactor ...still not working correctly
                  //  intensityTotal = MinimumValue; //Presumably White
                //if (intensityTotal < (MinimumValue - 1000))
                  //  intensityTotal = MaximumValue;

                if (intensityTotal > limit)
                    imageOut[offsetY, offsetX] = MinimumValue;
                else
                    imageOut[offsetY, offsetX] = MaximumValue;

                //imageOut[offsetY, offsetX] = (ushort)intensityTotal;
            }

        }

        SetImageArrayItem(ImageDataIndex.RAWData, new DiskBackedArray(imageOut));

    }
```

Just assume 'image_array', xDim, yDim are givens.  You'll notice some commented out other attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sobel (and other gradient-based filter) is suffered from noise. You can prefilter your picture with Gauss smoothing and compare results. Note that `limit = 1000000` for squared difference corresponds to diff magnitudes about 1000 - this is rather small value for 16-bit (MAX=65535) picture.
Saving in JPG makes a picture more blurred - sharp edges are smeared, high-frequency noise is lowered. So play a bit with mild smoothing and limit.

Comment: I've been fiddling with this for a while.  But then it dawned on me (bone-headedly) that this other software I spoke of, that made it look so easy was changing the size of the image to just the canvas size that I was seeing-- duh.  So instead of processing 5700*3700 image, it processes 550*780, I'm rounding of course, but you get the picture.  So yes, it is smoothing...  I'm still not quite done with this, but in the end, I'm getting my education.

Comment: The code above is totally not what I'm using anymore, but I am doing what your saying: Using Gaussian smoothing, than actually applying Kirsh edge detection... Thankx